# Making an application only visible to a certain user

Tags: permissions, files

I am new to Ubuntu and have recently installed applications through software center. These applications are visible and usable to all users, but I only want them visible and usable to me. How can I make sure an application can only be used and seen by me? I've done some searching and have not found anything.

Thanks

Comment: depending on the level of security: is this useful to you? http://askubuntu.com/a/548889/72216

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm - I am looking for a higher level of security because some of the applications, if tampered with, can take up large amounts of disk space. I looked at that and it is a good idea, its just not the level of security I would be looking for. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One way to figure this out would be to create a 'dummy'user and then log into your system as that user. I suspect that the applications will not be visible to that person. I dont think you will need to go to 'chown' for this.

Comment: Essentially I want to make certain applications invisible to future users and users that already exist. Is there a specific chown command for this?