# How could you password protect an application

Tags: zenity

How would you create A pop-up password dialogue using zenity (or other application) so that when a user tries to access a specified Applictaion it asks for a password

Comment: This might interest you as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/548568/how-to-block-specific-apps-from-opening-in-specific-accounts/548889#548889