# Prevent standard users from seeing and running some apps

Tags: 14.04, permissions, users, default-programs, administration

How to control just some apps to be available on other accounts, Not all of them?

Comment: How did you install Chromium on your computer? If you did it from the Software Center, the browser should be available to all users.

Comment: @pille1842 Sorry, you're right. I just edited my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to block specific apps from opening in specific accounts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/548568/how-to-block-specific-apps-from-opening-in-specific-accounts)

Comment: Also look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/445145/password-for-apps/445184#445184 and:http://askubuntu.com/questions/447043/exclude-user-from-using-systemwide-installed-programs/453790#453790

Comment: Is the visibility a big issue to you? In the first link, there is also an option to hide the application from Dash ("option 1").

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks a lot. Those were lucrative resources you'd answered before. Although my goal as a new user was to find a straightforward default option inside Ubuntu to do that, But your answers taught me some new aspects. Beside, I learnt it wouldn't be a crucial thing apps be visible. I'll come back to +1 your comments and answers as soon as I got the privilege. Thanks again

Comment: I am glad they were of some use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try changing the permissions of that program. I don't know if you can prevent a user from seeing the file, but you can definitely remove their permission to execute it.

You can remove everyone but the owners right to read, write, and execute the program.

`# removing read, write, execute privileges of "group" and "other" from the program file.`
`sudo chmod go-rwx <program file>`

If you want someone else to be able to be able to read, write, or execute that file then you can give the program file "group permissions" and add the the desired users to that files group.

`sudo chmod g+rwx <program file>`

`sudo useradd -G <UserToAddToGroup> <NameOfFilesGroup>`

I think if you spend a little time to learn the permission structure you will be able to accomplish what you are wanting to do.

Also, IIRC you could probably use sudoers to achieve your goals as well. This would be more complicated and require some reading.

You can modify sudoers with: `sudo visudo`

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was terse. Although I haven't applied it personally yet, but it seems rational. Thanks