# Restrict Programs For Certain Groups & Users

Tags: permissions

I am thinking about installing [Ubuntu MATE 14.04.3 LTS](https://ubuntu-mate.org/trusty/) onto several old computers in a school setting which currently run Windows XP.  These only are used for certain tasks.  I want it to where the users can only access certain programs.  For instance: Firefox, Chrome, Thunderbird, VLC, LibreOffice, Wine (for MS Office), and such need to be accessible.  I don't want them to access things that can mess up the computers easily (administrative things).  I know this usually requires sudo so maybe it will be safe as is and I can just remove the programs these users would never use.  Still, I would like to find some way to pick and choose what certain groups have access to like a program with check boxes to enable/disable programs.

This is all initially going to be an experiment so I am just trying to prepare for it if I decide to try this.  Most of the programs used are accessed with a web browser.  These users are not tech-savvy.  The goal is not to make them tech savvy but to allow the continued usage of old computers with a superior OS hopefully.

Comment: If they are not tech savvy, this should give you some options: http://askubuntu.com/a/548889/72216 Most (if not all) options should work on Mate as well as Unity. Please leave a comment if you manage or not.

Comment: Some more options: http://askubuntu.com/a/445184/72216 and http://askubuntu.com/a/453790/72216 and http://askubuntu.com/a/453845/72216