# How to prompt user for password and get result without gksudo?

Tags: bash, gksudo

There is no more `gksudo` command as well as `gksu` package in Ubuntu 18.04. How do I achieve the same using previous command like `DISPLAY=:0 gksudo -p -m "Enter your password to apply changes."` This basically asks user for password and returns the result. `pkexec` can't return the input password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password for apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445145/password-for-apps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use pkexec vs. gksu/gksudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo)

Comment: Which application program(s) do you try to run with elevated permissions?